# Merging multiple dataframes from dict

Tags: python, pandas

Give the following dict of DataFrames:

```
{

"01_2012": 
"Acc"  "B"   "F"
"011"   23   43
"012" 4324  432

"01_2013": 
"Acc" "B" "  F"
"011"   23   224
"012" 4324  453,

"01_2014": 
"Acc"  "B" "  F"
"011"   23    312
"012" 4324   500
"013: 4322   2120
}
```

Is it possible to merge all the dataframes on "Acc" key and add dict key name to the other cols?

So the end result would be:

```
"Acc"  "B_01_2012"  "F_01_2012" "B_01_2013" "F_01_2013" "B_01_2014" "F_01_2014" 
"011"   23               43            ...
"012"   4324            432
"013" Nan                Nan           Nan         Nan      4322        2120
```

Comment: Your dictionary is not valid.

Comment: try reduce merge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can do a concat:

```
pd.concat([d.set_index('Acc') for d in df_dicts.values()],
          keys=df_dicts.keys, axis=1)
```

Or

```
pd.concat([d.set_index('Acc').add_suffix(f'_{k}')
            for k,d in df_dicts.items()],
          axis=1)
```